# UIImagePickerController get image in an inherited

Tags: iphone, ios, delegates, camera, uiimagepickercontroller

I searched the internet for a solution but unfortunately I'm not able to find a solution to my problem.

Most people are creating an object of the `UIImagePickerController` class but I decided to do this on different way.

I created a new class `CameraViewController` this class extends of the `UIImagePickerController`.

My .h file:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface CameraViewController : UIImagePickerController <UIImagePickerControllerDelegate>

-(void)captureImage;

@end
```

My .m file:

```
#import "CameraViewController.h"

#define CAMERA_TRANSFORM_X 1
#define CAMERA_TRANSFORM_Y 1.5

@interface CameraViewController ()

@end

@implementation CameraViewController 

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 568)];
    UIButton *btnCapture = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake((320/2)-(76/2), 480, 76, 76)];
    [btnCapture setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"cam.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [btnCapture addTarget:self  action:@selector(captureImage) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    [view addSubview:btnCapture];

    self.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;

    self.showsCameraControls = NO;
    self.navigationBarHidden = YES;
    self.wantsFullScreenLayout = YES;
    self.cameraViewTransform = CGAffineTransformScale(self.cameraViewTransform, CAMERA_TRANSFORM_X, CAMERA_TRANSFORM_Y);
    self.cameraOverlayView = view;
    //[self openCamera];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

-(void)takePicture //overwrite take picture method
{
    [super takePicture];
    NSLog(@"%@", self);

}

-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    NSLog(@"%@", info);
}

-(void)captureImage
{
    [self takePicture];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

I implemented the delegate `UIImagePickerControllerDelegate`. But it seems that my `imagePickerController` is not called for some reason. In this method I try to log a `NSDirectory`. So I thought maybe I can get my image by overwriting the `takePicture` method, but I have no idea how. Anyone know how to help me? Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From apple docs `The UIImagePickerController class supports portrait mode only. This class is intended to be used as-is and does not support subclassing.`

So you can't subclass `UIImagePickerController`.

Comment: I'm using it in portrait. Are you serious, thats quite weird actually, why can't I use subclassing. I'm not changing anything, just trying to keep it simple and easy to use :(

Comment: Don't meter that you are using it in portrait and don't change anything, I think apple tries to protect the camera app and the way it's working so that it doesn't allow to subclass it. Maybe you don't want to change anything, but somewhere in the iOS world there will be developers that would change some stuffs in a good or bad way if the could subclass it so I think this is the main reason you can subclass it.

Comment: Apple is probably not allowing this because they don't want users to create an alternative for there own default app. Otherwise people could create an app that could take more then one picture without bringing up the camera up.